# Optional dependencyfor an android library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, rx-java, android-library

I have a [library](https://github.com/tushar-acharya/PrefCompat) which uses rxjava as a dependency. It is a wrapper class over SharedPreferences and also has RxJava support to listen on changes for any SharedPreference key. Now, I want to keep RxJava support as optional. i.e if a developer wants to use only the wrapper functionality, he should be able to use that without having the huge rxjava library imported as a dependency. Also he should be able to add RxJava support using an integration. For example, [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) has a base version of it's library and then has an okhttp integration which add some more functionality. I want to have something like that for my library. Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated :) Thank you

Comment: How about adding a new sub project and putting all RxJava support there?

Comment: Retrofit 1 has RxJava as optional, check out how their implementation :)

Comment: I did checkout existing projects like Retrofit, but there were so many other things in build.gradle files for each module so I couldn't figure out what is actually needed to achieve this